# Why is $\mathbf \nabla \cdot \mathbf {J} = 0$ where $\bf J$ is the current density?

Tags: conservation-laws, electric-current

This is quoted from Purcell's Electricity & Magnetism:

> ...if charge forever pours out of, or into, a fixed volume, the charge density inside must grow infinite, unless some compensating charge is continuously being created there. But charge creation is what never happens. Therefore for a truely time-independent current distribution, the surface integral of $\mathbf{J}$ must over any closed surface must go up to zero. $$\text{div} \mathbf{J} = 0$$

Can anyone please explain me what Purcell is telling?

Comment: You can look at this as Kirchhoff's law for currents entering and leaving nodes. This is simply another way to write it. Another way to imagine it would be to take a slice of a conductor and say all electrons go in one direction. The electrons that enter the conductor at 0mm will leave the conductor at 1mm, as no charges are created, you have a divergence(source) free field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without mathematics:

The divergence operator tells you the net flow into or out of a volume element. Imagine a car park. They count the number of cars that are coming in and the number going out, and a sign says "there are 5 spaces". Not because they count spaces- they count in and out flow.

For a steady state (same number of cars in the car park) the number going in must equal the number going out. And that is exactly what divergence = 0 means.

An illustrative joke: a mathematician watches a building. He sees two people going in and three people coming out. He says "if one more person goes in, the building will be empty again."

Comment: What does 'time-independent current' actually mean? BTW, the joke was really intuitive. +1.

Comment: Time-independent current means "the current is the same now as it was a second ago". If you had a net flow into a space, it would change the electric field (charge distribution) and you could not have a time-independent solution.

Comment: What does this line '...if charge forever pours out of, or into, a fixed volume, the charge density inside must grow infinite, unless some compensating charge is continuously being created there.' mean? Can you tell me?

Comment: "If cars keep coming into the car park and none come out, that must either mean there is a car-eating monster in the car park, or that the car park is bigger than you thought - like infinitely big, if you can keep this up indefinitely".

Comment: That is definitely a good explanation, sir. Purcell then talks about non-steady state where $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$. Can you tell me sir, how this scenario is different from the one that was described in the question? Does conservation law still apply?

Comment: Conservation laws still apply - but in that expression the charge density changes ("more cars came in than went out, so the number of cars in the car park has gone up"). That necessarily can only last for a finite time (not steady state).

Comment: How can conservation law be valid in the later case?

Comment: Total charge is conserved, not necessarily local charge. Total number of cars on road + in car park = constant (unless cars get produced / destroyed somewhere). But number in car park may change - within limits.

Answer (score 6):

He is saying that the surface integral over any closed surface must be zero for time-independent current distribution, because otherwise there is a net flux of charge into or out of a volume, and we can't have that going on indefinitely. If $\Sigma$ is a volume with surface $\partial\Sigma$, we have by [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) that
$$ \int_{\Sigma} \vec\nabla \cdot\vec J = \int_{\partial\Sigma}\vec J = 0$$
Since this must hold for *any* volume $\Sigma$, $\vec \nabla\cdot \vec J = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

This is arising from the charge [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation).  This condition occurs when $\partial \rho / \partial t$ = 0 because the full equation is given by:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} = 0
$$
if there are no sources or sinks.  So without charge creation, this holds.

**Example Application**
Consequently, the restriction that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} = 0$ also occurs when one considers [magnetized shocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocks_and_discontinuities_(magnetohydrodynamics)).  To get a stationary solution one must assume that the shock ramp is not reforming and there exists a reference frame in which the shock is at rest.  If $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} \neq 0$, then the shock cannot be stationary, as this would imply a net current along the shock normal vector.  A potential source of such a case could be reflected particles or waves caused by dispersive radiation (i.e., the current acts like an antenna and radiates a wave).

**Side Note**
ACuriousMind's answer is correct as well.

Comment: Yes, I know that $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} = 0$. But in Purcell, both the equations are given; mine is for steady state & yours for non-steady state. Can you tell me what's the difference between the two states?

Comment: Steady state is when $\partial \rho / \partial t$ = 0 or more generally, when $\partial / \partial t$ = 0 for any given quantity.  This is the simplest way to think about it, but I think there are more rigorous definitions of steady state but I am distracted at the moment.